# Angular $localStorage Save After Browser Close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am trying to save data with `$localStorage`, even after the all browser windows/tabs are closed. How do I go about this?

Comment: Please add more information as to what you have tried and what didnot work?

Comment: I have tried assignments using `$localStorage.variable = data` & `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith")`and it seems like the some of the data is being saved, but I am losing parts of it. I can close tabs associated with the page but keep the browser open and it is functioning. But when the whole browser is closed, it seems like the $localStorage is flushed

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean saving as the browser is closing? Once the browser (or just your tab) is closed, your code will stop running.

If that is what you are looking for, then this should do the trick.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    //localStorage saving here
    return null; //Will not halt the unload from happening
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

However, do note, that that function will get called any time the page is left, from navigating away (clicking a link) or the tab/browser being closed.

Comment: not quite, while that would help, i want to be able to save the data, close the browser then open it back up with my saved data still existing.

Comment: That's what localStorage does. You save once when the app is open, by writing to localStorage, and then next time the page loads, the data from the previous time you wrote to localStorage is already there, you don't have to do anything special to commit/write it other than the call to localStorage.setItem(). It just gets written, and can be grabbed with localStorage.getItem() on the next page load.